# Calling system() on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, std, jailbreak

I'm trying to make calls via the C system() function in an application for jailbroken iPhones, but they don't seem to be working. I know it's possible, because the source code for Cydia.app does it, but when I try it, it does nothing.

I set up a simple test, which works fine on the Mac, but comes back empty on device:

```
system("cd /bin && ls > /tmp/output.txt");
NSLog([NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/output.txt" usedEncoding:nil error:nil]);
```

I'm installing this normally, through XCode. I thought I might need to install it in /Applications, but when I try to SSH in and install it in /Applications, it shows up in SpringBoard, but refuses to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> system("cd /bin && ls > /tmp/output.txt");
> ```

Maybe your /bin is just empty, or maybe you don't even have one (I'm not sure what an iPhone's file-system looks like). Try something like `echo foo > /tmp/output.txt` instead.

That's assuming that /tmp is even writable+existent.

> ```
> NSLog([NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/output.txt" usedEncoding:nil error:nil]);
> ```

Don't pass random strings to `NSLog`. Use a format string, even if it's just `@"%@"`, and pass the string object as one of the items to be formatted into it.

Also, you should not pass `nil` for either of these output parameters. You can pass `NULL` for the encoding parameter if you really don't care what encoding it is, but you should always pass a pointer to accept an error object, if nothing else so that the framework can tell you why this isn't working (this may be the actual failure point).

Comment: /tmp is definitely existant and writeable, I can run this command from Mobile Terminal, and it returns fine. I guess now my question is how I can install my app in /Applications; I have a strong suspicion that'll fix it.